# Filter is Stripping URL with custom scheme

Tags: uri

There are times we are using custom schemes for URLs and storing them in Drupal 6.

The href attribute values are getting stored in the db properly.

So,

```
<a href="mycustomscheme://foo/bar">
```

gets stored as it's written. However, when viewing the page the unknown scheme gets stripped so it outputs:

```
<a href="//foo/bar">
```

I've disabled all filters in the full HTML input format and have returned out of my hook_nodeapi function in my custom module, and disabled the WYSIWIG, and still the scheme gets stripped.

Any ideas where this might be happening?

Comment: Does it still strip it if you change the input format to php code? You might have to enable the core php module to see this option.

Comment: No, that didn't do it. I enabled it, and selected it as the default filter, but the custom scheme is still getting stripped.

Comment: Setting it as the default will not change nodes that have already been saved.

Comment: That worked! Can you tell me why?

Comment: I see, it's the HTML filter that's doing it. But there's no way to configure it to not strip it. I still want it, because I want it to strip certain tags, but not the custom schemes. Is my alternative (other than hacking the filter code) to write my own filter on top, that puts the scheme back in?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend hacking the HTML filter in core. If you want you could copy/modify it into your own module and create your own filter, here is a [link to a blog post](http://definitivedrupal.org/node/90) that should help get your started.

Or you could try one of the contrib packages like [Custom Filter](http://drupal.org/project/customfilter).